# How to include optional in array in Swift

Tags: swift

I want to insert an optional in an array as follows

```
let arr: AnyObject[] = [1, 2, nil, 4, 5]
```

The following expression throws a compile error saying

```
Cannot convert the expression's type 'AnyObject[]' to type 'AnyObject'
```

How can I made this work? I need optional or nil value in the array even though I know I shouldn't.

Answer (score 21):

If you're just going to be inserting either `Int`s or `nil`s, use

**Swift < 2.0**

```
var arr: Int?[] = [1, 2, nil, 4, 5]
```

**Swift >= 2.0**

```
var arr: [Int?] = [1, 2, nil, 4, 5]
```

**Swift 3x**

```
var arr: Array<Int?> = [1, 2, nil, 4, 5]
```

This can be done for any type (not just `Int`; that is if you want an `array` to hold a specific type but allow it to be empty in some indices, like say a carton of eggs.)

Answer (score 7):

Just like this:

```
let arr: AnyObject?[] = [1, 2, nil, 4, 5]
```

it makes the Array of type `AnyObject?`

Answer (score 5):

You can't use `AnyObject`:

```
 18> let ar : AnyObject?[] = [1, 2, nil, 4, 5]
<REPL>:18:25: error: cannot convert the expression's type 'AnyObject?[]' to type 'AnyObject?'
let ar : AnyObject?[] = [1, 2, nil, 4, 5]
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

But you can use `Any`:

```
 18> let ar : Any?[] = [1, 2, nil, 4, 5]
ar: Any?[] = size=5 {
  [0] = Some {
    Some = <read memory from 0x7f8d4b841dc0 failed (0 of 8 bytes read)>
  }
  [1] = Some {
    Some = <read memory from 0x7f8d50da03c0 failed (0 of 8 bytes read)>
  }
  [2] = Some {
    Some = nil
  }
  [3] = Some {
    Some = <read memory from 0x7f8d4be77160 failed (0 of 8 bytes read)>
  }
  [4] = Some {
    Some = <read memory from 0x7f8d4be88480 failed (0 of 8 bytes read)>
  }
}
```

The Apple documentation makes this clear:

> “Swift provides two special type aliases for working with non-specific
>   types:
>     o AnyObject can represent an instance of any class type.
>     o Any can represent an instance of any type at all, apart from function types.”
>
> Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language.” iBooks.
>   https://itun.es/us/jEUH0.l

It appears that `Int` and probably other primitive types are not subtypes of a class type and thus `AnyObject` won't work.

Answer (score 3):

`let ar: AnyObject[] = [1,2,nil,3]` is illegal because `nil` is not convertible to `AnyObject`.

`let a: AnyObject?[] = [1,3,nil,2]` or `let a: Int?[] = [1,3,nil,2]` works.

If you need an Objective-C bridgeable  Array use

`let a: AnyObject[] = [1, 2, NSNull(), 4, 5]`

Answer (score 1):

It's a cheat, but if you're using the nil as a sentinel it might be advisable to just use Tuples, one element being a `Bool` to rep the validity of the second.

```
var arr = [(true, 1), (true, 2) , (false, 0) , (true, 4),(true,5)]
```